# Copy Attribute Model to clipboard

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, copy, clipboard

i'm trying to copy the attribute of my backbone model to the clipboard.

I'm trying to use the "document.execCommand('copy'), but it doesn't work.

In my HTML i have a button, and when i click on it a function is called, this is the simple code i'm trying (not even trying to get the attribute from the model, just a normal text)

```
onClick: function(){
   var attributeCopied = 'try me'; 
   document.execCommand('copy');
}
```

Of course, this doesn't work, and i don't know how to make my "attributeCopied" variable to be copied when the command 'copy' is launched (maybe trying something like .select()? but it didn't work either) Or maybe it can't be done?

Can you help me? Thank you!!

EDIT: Hi again! well i'm still trying to do it, the problem here is the variable i want to copy doesn't appear in the HTML, it's only accesible inside my View (i'm ussing marionette too by the way) and i haven't figured out yet how to "attach" my variable so when the document.execCommand('copy') is fired, it is copied, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here JavaScript copy content example. Hope you get an idea from this.

```js
function copy(target) {
  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
  var ps = document.querySelector(target);
  var range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNode(ps);
  window.getSelection().addRange(range);
  try {
    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
    alert('Copy command was ' + msg + ' : ' + range);
  } catch (err) {
    alert('Oops, unable to copy');
  }
  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
}
```

```html
<div class="text">Content</div>
<a href="javascript: copy('.text');">Copy</a>
```

Comment: Hi! Yes, I already tryed something like that. The problem here, is the variable i'm trying to copy is an attribute from a backbone model, and it isn't shown in the HTML, so i can't use the document.querySelector over it